# Receiving error after running ggplot() code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to run the `R` code for a recently published manuscript. Here is the code that I am working with:

```
prop_full <- import("ProductivePacifists_Data.RData")

# Subset to variables included in the models.
prop <- prop_full %>% dplyr::select(gwno, country, tc_dummy_ICOW, tc_resource_dummy_ICOW, 
                              tc_mid_dummy_ICOW, tc_mid_resource_dummy_ICOW, 
                              tc_resource_count_ICOW,
                              land_oriented_medium_binary, 
                              land_oriented_medium_continuous, 
                              resource_dependent_7.5, ag_dependent_15, 
                              autocracy_BX, milper_MC, milex_constant2010us_AFM,
                              milex_gdp_estimate_AFM,
                              WorldBank_gdppc_2010_con_estimate, CINC_tpop_estimate, 
                              land_CONT, island_CONT, trade_WDI, spatial_count_TR, 
                              spatial_dummy_TR, year)

# Create time variables. Page 568: following Carter & Signorino (2010).
prop <- prop %>% mutate(year2 = (year)^2/1000, year3 = (year)^3/100000)


#### Figure 1 ####

# Organize data frame capturing proportion of land-oriented per year.
prop_yr <- prop %>% group_by(year) %>% filter(year<2014) %>%
          summarise (land_prop = mean(land_oriented_medium_binary, na.rm=T))

fig1 <- ggplot(data=prop_yr, aes(x=year)) +
        geom_line(aes(y=land_prop), size=.5) +
        geom_area(aes(y=land_prop), alpha=.1) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1825, 2000, 25)) +
        labs(x="Year", y="", title = "Proportion of Land-Oriented Economies") +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
fig1
```

When I run `fig1` I receive the following error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'year' not found`. Does anyone know why this is the case? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include a reproducible example of your data  ``dput(prop_full)`` or else it's going to be very hard for anyone to help you. My guess is that this is something caused by aesthetics inheritance but it's impossible to say otherwise.

Comment: try  `prop_yr = prop_yr %>% ungroup()` then plot..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using a different data source; it seems to work for me without errors when I do:

```r
download.file("https://github.com/scmulesky/ProductivePacifistsRepo/raw/master/ProductivePacifists_Data.RDATA", destfile = "ProductivePacifists_Data.RDATA")
load("ProductivePacifists_Data.RDATA")
prop_full <- prop1
```

Reproducible code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
download.file("https://github.com/scmulesky/ProductivePacifistsRepo/raw/master/ProductivePacifists_Data.RDATA", destfile = "ProductivePacifists_Data.RDATA")
load("ProductivePacifists_Data.RDATA")
prop_full <- prop1



# Subset to variables included in the models.
prop <- prop_full %>% dplyr::select(gwno, country, tc_dummy_ICOW, tc_resource_dummy_ICOW, 
                                    tc_mid_dummy_ICOW, tc_mid_resource_dummy_ICOW, 
                                    tc_resource_count_ICOW,
                                    land_oriented_medium_binary, 
                                    land_oriented_medium_continuous, 
                                    resource_dependent_7.5, ag_dependent_15, 
                                    autocracy_BX, milper_MC, milex_constant2010us_AFM,
                                    milex_gdp_estimate_AFM,
                                    WorldBank_gdppc_2010_con_estimate, CINC_tpop_estimate, 
                                    land_CONT, island_CONT, trade_WDI, spatial_count_TR, 
                                    spatial_dummy_TR, year)


# Create time variables. Page 568: following Carter & Signorino (2010).
prop <- prop %>% mutate(year2 = (year)^2/1000, year3 = (year)^3/100000)


#### Figure 1 ####

# Organize data frame capturing proportion of land-oriented per year.
prop_yr <- prop %>% group_by(year) %>% filter(year<2014) %>%
    summarise (land_prop = mean(land_oriented_medium_binary, na.rm=T))

fig1 <- ggplot(data=prop_yr, aes(x=year)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=land_prop), size=.5) +
    geom_area(aes(y=land_prop), alpha=.1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1825, 2000, 25)) +
    labs(x="Year", y="", title = "Proportion of Land-Oriented Economies") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
fig1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code.
I used the `csv` format form github source and it worked.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

prop_full <- read.csv("https://github.com/scmulesky/ProductivePacifistsRepo/blob/master/ProductivePacifists_Data.csv")

prop <- prop_full %>% dplyr::select(gwno, country, tc_dummy_ICOW, tc_resource_dummy_ICOW,
                                    tc_mid_dummy_ICOW, tc_mid_resource_dummy_ICOW,
                                    tc_resource_count_ICOW,
                                    land_oriented_medium_binary,
                                    land_oriented_medium_continuous,
                                    resource_dependent_7.5, ag_dependent_15,
                                    autocracy_BX, milper_MC, milex_constant2010us_AFM,
                                    milex_gdp_estimate_AFM,
                                    WorldBank_gdppc_2010_con_estimate, CINC_tpop_estimate,
                                    land_CONT, island_CONT, trade_WDI, spatial_count_TR,
                                    spatial_dummy_TR, year)

# Create time variables. Page 568: following Carter & Signorino (2010).
prop <- prop %>% mutate(year2 = (year)^2/1000, year3 = (year)^3/100000)


#### Figure 1 ####

# Organize data frame capturing proportion of land-oriented per year.
prop_yr <- prop %>% group_by(year) %>% filter(year<2014) %>%
  summarise (land_prop = mean(land_oriented_medium_binary, na.rm=T))

fig1 <- ggplot(data=prop_yr, aes(x=year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=land_prop), size=.5) +
  geom_area(aes(y=land_prop), alpha=.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1825, 2000, 25)) +
  labs(x="Year", y="", title = "Proportion of Land-Oriented Economies") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
fig1
```

[image]